# Single @RequestMapping for multiple controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, request-mapping

I'm trying to create a single `@RequestMapping` value for 2 or 3 controllers unfortunately I'm getting error

Eg:

```
@Controller
public class contatcs {

  @RequestMapping(value="Save", params="m=contacts")
  public ModelAndView SaveContacts(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/savecontacts");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="update", params="m=contacts")
  public ModelAndView UpdateContacts(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/updatecontacts");
  }
}



@Controller
public class clients {

  @RequestMapping(value="Save", params="m=clients")
  public ModelAndView SaveClients(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/saveclients");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="update", params="m=clients")
  public ModelAndView updateClients(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/updateclients");
  }
}
```

in above I use `Save` in 2 controller so I'm getting error If I use with single controller it works as I expected

Error is:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler [clients] to URL path [//save]: There is already handler [crm.venkat.controller.Clients@7e47dc12] mapped.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot map handler [clientCompaniesController] to URL path [//Search]: There is already handler [crm.venkat.controller.ClientCompaniesController@7e47dc12] mapped.
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:376)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.registerHandler(AbstractUrlHandlerMapping.java:348)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.detectHandlers(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:82)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.initApplicationContext(AbstractDetectingUrlHandlerMapping.java:58)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationObjectSupport.initApplicationContext(WebApplicationObjectSupport.java:71)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationObjectSupport.setApplicationContext(ApplicationObjectSupport.java:73)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.invokeAwareInterfaces(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(ApplicationContextAwareProcessor.java:82)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:394)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
    ... 20 more
```

Comment: It says right here »Cannot map handler [clientCompaniesController] to URL path [//Search]: There is already handler« where the cause lies.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot have same `url-mapping` for various controllers however what you can do is:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/contacts") //line added here
public class contatcs {

  @RequestMapping(value="/Save", params="m=contacts")
  public ModelAndView SaveContacts(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/savecontacts");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/update", params="m=contacts") 
  public ModelAndView UpdateContacts(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/updatecontacts");
  }
}



@Controller
@RequestMapping("/clients") //line added here
public class clients {

  @RequestMapping(value="/Save", params="m=clients")
  public ModelAndView SaveClients(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/saveclients");
  }

  @RequestMapping(value="/update", params="m=clients")
  public ModelAndView updateClients(@ModelAttribute("command") ContactsBean contactsBean,
        BindingResult result)
    //some stuff
    return new ModelAndView("/updateclients");
  }
}
```

Now what you can do is fire a url `/contacts/Save` that would get the control in `contacts` class' `SaveContacts` method and `/clients/Save` would go to `client` class' `SaveClients` method. And similarly for update.